# How can I get httpOnly cookies in next13 server component?

Tags: cookies, next.js13

A little background first: To authenticate users im using JWT tokens, stored in httpOnly cookies, which should be sent along with every request from my client to my backend.
The problem is - when i send a request from a server side component, the cookies aren't being sent with the request. I tried to get the cookies manually and add them to the request headers like this:

```js
const HomePage = async () => {
  const accessToken = cookies().get("accessToken")?.value;
  const refreshToken = cookies().get("refreshToken")?.value;
  // attach those cookies to the request
}
```

The problem with this is it only works in development, since the client can't access httpOnly cookies in production.

Is there a way I can send a request with these httpOnly cookies from a server component? Or do I have to use client?
It's Important to note that my backend is an external app, I'm not using the nextjs backend.

Comment: Hey there, did you get this figured out?

Comment: @amieWilt after researching for weeks and not finding anything that points me in the right direction I finally gave that up, I believe it's not currently possible on next.js 13 otherwise I would have found something